# Sorting list with searched input string

Tags: android, sorting, listview, search

I am working on a Parse/Android application in which I am getting array list of objects from the server, for example Apple, Banana, Carrot, Dino etc which I am displaying in my Adapter.

Now I want to make a search thing on my list, if I press any alphabet it will show the items according to those characters, for example: if I press "A" so it will show me : Apple, Apricot etc and do not show any other.

My code is given below:

```
// mItems is my arraylist of objects with "title" object.
mItems = (ArrayList<ParseObject>) objects;
mAdapter = new GenericAdapter<ParseObject>(getApplicationContext(), 
mItems,R.layout.listview_dical_assist,mNotificationsBinder);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

My autoComplete editField where I want to make that sorting list thing.

```
autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

              @Override
              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

               // I need to put that search query here user press any character

               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              }

              @Override
              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                      int arg3) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }

              @Override
              public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }
          });
```

Comment: You need an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: Yes, basically i need to make search functionality on my list, so if i press any character on edit field it should show those items on my list view. example if i press "Ap" it should show APPLE in my listview vice versa